# What does static for operator new mean

Tags: c++

what does static for operator new mean here? what would happen if i put it in a header file?

```
static void* operator new(size_t size, std::string s)
{
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles on visual studio 2013

But gcc gives an error

> error: 'void* operator new(size_t)' may not be declared
>   as static
>
> static void* operator new(size_t size)

And so does clang

> error: static declaration of 'operator new' follows non-static
>   declaration
>
> static void* operator new(size_t size)

Is this a gray area in c++, or is visual studio being generous?

link to the code: https://www.ideone.com/kZmWgf

Comment: VS is being generous.

Comment: `static` would be mandatory for a class-level custom allocation function, but does not really make sense, if it's a global allocation function.

Comment: VS is not generous: "error C2323: 'operator new': non-member operator new or delete functions may not be declared static or in a namespace other than the global namespace".  Your VS version is old.  Having the operator replaced in one source code file but not another does not often pan out well.  So you'd better fix it.

Comment: @Hans Passant Please do mention the version of vs

Comment: Got that from VS2017 version 15.5.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`static` is useless for the global `operator new`. VS C++ compiler is generous: `void *operator new` is declared as non-static already and can not be declared the second time as static, GCC and clang inform you about it.

`static` is applicable to overloaded custom `operator new` for class objects. `static` is required there since the operator new is used for allocation of an object and `this` will be available first after allocation, in other words `operator new` returns `this` pointer first.

Please note, according to the Standard

> **15.5 Free store**
>
> Any allocation function for a class T is a static member (even if not
>   explicitly declared static).